# Footer at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I want that my footer is on the bottom of the page, but it won't work. There is always a scrollbar, why is that?

http://www.yannickluijten.be/luc/website/

```
#top {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: #00aeef;
```

}

```
#wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 960px;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -20px;
```

}

```
#footerbg {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
background: #d7d7d7;
```

}

```
.push {
height: 20px;
```

}

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footerbg"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wrapper should be a container for the content

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/F577v/

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <div id="content"><p>content here</p></div>
</div>
<div id="footerbg"></div>
```

​

I made the footer snap to the bottom outside of the wrapper, if you want to move the top outside that is also fine but remember you will have to adjust the bottom padding to compensate for its height too.

view the updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/F577v/2/

Comment: take a look here: http://www.yannickluijten.be/luc/website/ the top(blue bar) has to be a width of 100% so it can't be in the wrapper? and yes there has to be a space between the blue and the red bar

Comment: Still not working, my top also has to be out of the wrapper. How do I have to that then?

Comment: just move it outside, as so in the edit. @user1211376 , is the logic of what i showed you the solution you are looking for or am i batting in the wrong area?

Comment: It's almost good, if I put my <div id="top"> in my wrapper then it's working. But if you saw my top has to have a 100% width, so the top-div may not be in the wrapper.

Comment: @user1211376 did you adjust the bottom padding? if you need to create another div to wrap everything in then you could call it page_wrapper and then continue to use your wrapper inside

Comment: Hm I don't get it, I guess the problem is that my top(not in wrapper) has a height of 50px and my wrapper has a height of 100% so my footerbg is 50px below it has to be?

Comment: @user1211376 please look here http://jsfiddle.net/F577v/3/ is this what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/F577v/8/

First of all, your containers don't need to be relative position.
Second of all, footer should be centered by setting a width and left/right margins to auto:

```
#footerbg {
    width: 960px;
    ....
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}​
```

Comment: @user1211376 You haven't explainded what exactly you want to achieve. Does the footer need to be full screen wide or centered as I did?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1) put the `footerbg` inside the `wrapper`

2) put in the `footerbg` the same style as in wrapper (same **width** & **margin** values)